# Re-using ansible variables saved by register

Tags: ansible

can someone explain why the following happens:

I am trying to re-use the same variable (`output`) in two different tasks, of which only one task will run depending on a conditional (`bool`). I don't understand why when the following playbook is run, the `debug hi` task results in an error.

The `echo hello` and `debug hello` run and work as expected and then the `echo hi` is skipped (which is also expected as `bool == True`) but I don't understand why the `debug hi` results in an error. The error I get is:

`The conditional check output.stdout == hi failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional: output 'dict object' has no attribute stdout`

Why doesn't the the `output` variable persist through the `debug hi` task? It's almost as if it is losing its value when `debug hi` is skipped.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    bool: True

  tasks:
  - name: echo hello
    shell: echo "hello"
    register: output
    when: bool == True

  - name: debug hello
    debug:
      msg: "hello"
    when: output.stdout == "hello"

  - name: echo hi
    shell: echo "hi"
    register: output
    when: bool != True

  - name: debug hi
    debug:
      msg: "hi"
    when: output.stdout == "hi"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are still registering the task result to `output`, even though the task was skipped. Take these very simple tasks for example:

```
  - command: echo Hello
    register: result
    when: false

  - debug:
      var: result
```

The variable `result` is still created, and has the following contents:

```
    "result": {
        "changed": false,
        "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False",
        "skipped": true
    }
```

This is still very useful information (i.e. to know that a task was skipped). You will need to account for this logic in your plays.

Answer (score 0):

This task:

```
- name: echo hi
    shell: echo "hi"
    register: output
    when: bool != True
```

registers `output` whether `bool` is true or not.

See the [ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables).

> If a task fails or is skipped, the variable still is registered with a failure or skipped status, the only way to avoid registering a variable is using tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your latest `when:` condition with:

```
when: output.stdout is defined and output.stdout == "hi"
```